# ALAssetsLibrary returns same assets after adding new photo to camera roll - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary

I'm using `ALAssetsLibrary` to enumerate first 30 photos in my Saved photos. I've created property in `AppDelegate` to have access to `ALAssets` everytime when I want, because lifetime of `ALAssetsLibrary` instance is tied to `ALAssets` lifetime.
Here is my code:

```
if(!_savedAssets) _savedAssets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
else [_savedAssets removeAllObjects];

if(appDelegate.library)
{
    [appDelegate.library release];
    [appDelegate setLibrary:nil];
}

appDelegate.library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
__block int count = 0;
[appDelegate.library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%d",group.numberOfAssets);
    if(count>30) *stop = YES;
    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *needToStop) {
        NSLog(@"%d", index);
        if(count<30 && result)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:result.thumbnail];
            [_savedAssets addObject:result];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageManipulation:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
            count++;

        }
        else
          *needToStop = YES;

    }];
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
}];
```

As you can see, I'm adding first 30 `ALAssets` to my `NSMutableArray`, to have access to thumbnail or fullsize image. After my app makes photo, I save this photo to camera roll and try to reload my `ALAssets` with same code as when I load them first time. Before reloading, I remove all objects from `NSMutableArray`, and reinitializing `ALAssetsLibrary`. But this not helps. Each time I get same `ALAssets`. 
I get new `ALAssets` only after reloading app. How to reload `ALAssets` without reloading app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register an observer for `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification`.
When the notification fires, reload the assets.