# detect when user take a picture or when a new image is added to the camera roll

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, alassetslibrary

In my app, I have an Image View showing the most recent image from the Camera Roll.

I want it to always be updated so I need a way to detect when a new image was added to the Camera Roll.

Is there a notification when user take a picture from the camera or a screenshot?
Or even better is there a notification that a new image added to the Camera Roll?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038225/alassetslibrary-returns-same-assets-after-adding-new-photo-to-camera-roll-obje

Comment: What code are you using to get the most recent image? If you wanted it to be updated wouldn't you use the same code in ViewDidAppear?

Comment: @Benny, for example what if the user take a screen shot while using the app, I stil want to know that...